# How to get page redirecting URL in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So say I need to get the URL of a page in vb.net but the only way to get to said page is with a redirect.

Like this:
http://example.com/users/usertypeimg.php?id=1

Redirects to:
http://example.com/img/usertypemega.png

How would I tell what the endpoint of a redirect is (and get just the URL)

Comment: Depends on the framework you are using.

Comment: @litelite I'm using .NET framework 4.5.2

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour] this is not how good questions are asked (as evidenced by the downvotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HttpClient` class will automatically redirect for you, so all you should need to do is send a `GET` message to the original URL, and then just read the actual redirected URL from the response:

```
Public Async Function GetRedirectedUrl(originalUrl As String) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Dim client As New HttpClient()
    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync("http://example.com/users/usertypeimg.php?id=1")
    Return response.Headers.Location.ToString()
End Function
```